# Difference between BeautifulSoup and Scrapy crawler?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to make a website that shows the comparison between amazon and e-bay product price.
Which of these will work better and why? I am somewhat familiar with **BeautifulSoup** but not so much with **Scrapy crawler**.

Comment: Why would you use crawlers when both those sites have a great API? http://aws.amazon.com/python/ http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/

Comment: i am from India and i think ***Amazon-Api*** does not support india host. there is no **api(locale)** for india. ***HOSTS = {'ca': 'ecs.amazonaws.ca', 'cn': 'webservices.amazon.cn', 'de': 'ecs.amazonaws.de', 'es': 'webservices.amazon.es', 'fr': 'ecs.amazonaws.fr', 'it': 'webservices.amazon.it', 'jp': 'ecs.amazonaws.jp', 'uk': 'ecs.amazonaws.co.uk', 'us': 'ecs.amazonaws.com',}***

Comment: And what if i want to crawl some other site that does not have API ?

Comment: @InbarRose Using Amazon's product API requires an Amazon Associate account.

Comment: [bs4](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enIR807IR807&sxsrf=ALeKk02DFus8BwFpEc75ADYWMB0q_WJc4g%3A1602802535736&ei=Z9OIX765LMXD8gKigo-oBg&q=python+beautifulsoup&oq=python+beautifulsoup&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCCMQyQMQJzICCAAyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAUPQbWL8dYPUgaABwAXgAgAHUAYgBogOSAQMyLTKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj-iKbe2LfsAhXFoVwKHSLBA2UQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) vs [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

**Scrapy** is a Web-spider or **web scraper framework**, You give Scrapy a root URL to start crawling, then you can specify constraints on how many (number of) URLs you want to crawl and fetch,etc. It is a complete framework for web-scraping or **crawling**.

While

**BeautifulSoup** is a **parsing library** which also does a pretty good job of fetching contents from URL and allows you to parse certain parts of them without any hassle. It only fetches the contents of the URL that you give and then stops. It does not crawl unless you manually put it inside an infinite loop with certain criteria.

In simple words, with Beautiful Soup you can build something similar to Scrapy.
Beautiful Soup is a **library** while Scrapy is a **complete framework**.

[Source](http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/How-is-BeautifulSoup-different-from-Scrapy)

Comment: which is faster , I mean i am using BeautifulSoup  and it takes around 10sec to scrap data ? does scrapy faster than beautifulsoup ?

Comment: If you use beautifulsoup with blocking code, scrapy should be faster as long as there are independent requests to make, but I guess you can also use beautifulsoup with asyncio to achieve better performance.

Comment: I would say, Scrapy along with BeautifulSoup will be super fast and you would be able to get the best out of both.

Comment: Scrapy supports asynchronous requests out of the box while with beautifulsoup you'd have to use one of the asynchronous clients, like aiohttp client.

Answer (score 21):

I think both are good... im doing a project right now that use both. First i scrap all the pages using scrapy and save that on a mongodb collection using their pipelines, also downloading the images that exists on the page.
After that i use BeautifulSoup4 to make a pos-processing where i must change attributes values and get some special tags.

If you don't know which pages products you want, a good tool will be scrapy since you can use their crawlers to run all amazon/ebay website looking for the products without making a explicit for loop.

Take a look at the scrapy documentation, it's very simple to use.

Comment: So can i use **Scrapy** on web server because there are many dependencies of it like (Twisted, pywin32, pyOpenSSL ete..). (Sorry for this silly question, i am new to python)

Comment: On the web server? I never try that... i use it on the shell, execute the "scrapy crawl <name of crawler>" to run the spider... perhaps you could use this on the server, but you have to call this using the python subprocess module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

As i said never try this, but perhaps it could work... just a note, use the log message from scrapy just for you to know where erros might happen on your crawler (from scrapy import log).

Answer (score 16):

**[Scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**
It is a **web scraping framework** which comes with tons of goodies which make scraping from easier so that we can focus on crawling logic only. Some of my favourite things scrapy takes care for us are below.

- [Feed exports](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html): It basically allows us to save data in various formats like CSV,JSON,jsonlines and XML.
- Asynchronous scraping: Scrapy uses twisted framework which gives us power to visit multiple urls at once where each request is processed in non blocking way(Basically we don't have to wait for a request to finish before sending another request).
- [Selectors](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/selectors.html): This is where we can compare scrapy with beautiful soup. Selectors are what allow us to select particular data from the webpage like heading, certain div with a class name etc.). Scrapy uses lxml for parsing which is extremely fast than beautiful soup.
- Setting proxy,user agent ,headers etc: scrapy allows us to set and rotate proxy,and other headers dynamically.
- [Item Pipelines](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html): Pipelines enable us to process data after extraction. For example we can configure pipeline to push data to your mysql server.
- Cookies: scrapy automatically handles cookies for us.

etc.

> TLDR: scrapy is a framework that provides everything that one might
>   need to build large scale crawls. It provides various features that
>   hide complexity of crawling the webs. one can simply start writing web
>   crawlers without worrying about the setup burden.

**[Beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)**
Beautiful Soup is a Python package for **parsing HTML and XML documents**. So with Beautiful soup you can parse a webpage that has been already downloaded. BS4 is very popular and old. Unlike scrapy,**You cannot use beautiful soup only to make crawlers**. You will need other libraries like requests,urllib etc to make crawlers with bs4. Again, this means you would need to manage the list of urls being crawled,to be crawled, handle cookies , manage proxy, handle errors, create your own functions to push data to CSV,JSON,XML etc. If you want to speed up than you will have to use other libraries like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.htmlhttps://).

To sum up.

- Scrapy is a rich framework that you can use to start writing crawlers
  without any hassale.
- Beautiful soup is a library that you can use to parse a webpage. It
  cannot be used alone to scrape web.

**You should definitely use scrapy for your amazon and e-bay product price comparison website. You could build a database of urls and run the crawler every day(cron jobs,Celery for scheduling crawls) and update the price on your database.This way your website will always pull from the database and crawler and database will act as individual components.**

Answer (score 3):

Both are using to parse data.

**Scrapy**:

- Scrapy is a fast high-level web crawling and web scraping framework,
  used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages.
- But it has some limitations when data comes from java script or
  loading dynamicaly, we can over come it by using packages like splash, 
  selenium etc.

**BeautifulSoup**:

- Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and
  XML files.
- we can use this package for getting data from java script or 
  dynamically loading pages.

Scrapy with BeautifulSoup is one of the best combo we can work with for scraping static and dynamic contents

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is to use the eBay/Amazon API's rather than scrapy, and then parse the results using BeautifulSoup.

The APIs gives you an official way of getting the same data that you would have got from scrapy crawler, with no need to worry about hiding your identity, mess about with proxies,etc.

Comment: The question clearly asks for solutions where APIs are not available.

Comment: Also, just curious.  If you're actually using the API (which returns JSON) why would you need Beautiful Soup to parse?

Answer (score 2):

**BeautifulSoup** is a library that lets you extract information from a web page.

**Scrapy** on the other hand is a framework, which does the above thing and many more things you probably need in your scraping project like pipelines for saving data.

You can check this blog to get started with Scrapy
https://www.inkoop.io/blog/web-scraping-using-python-and-scrapy/

Answer (score 1):

Using **scrapy** you can save tons of code and start with structured programming, If you dont like any of the scapy's pre-written methods then **BeautifulSoup** can be used in the place of scrapy method.
Big project takes both advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Beautifulsoup is web scraping small library. it does your job but sometime it does not satisfy your needs.i mean if you scrape  websites in large amount of data  so here in this case beautifulsoup fails.

In this case  you should use Scrapy which is  a complete  scraping framework  which will do you job.
Also scrapy has support for databases(all kind of databases) so it is a huge
of scrapy over other web  scraping libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are many and selection of any tool/technology depends on individual needs.

Few major differences are:

1. BeautifulSoup is comparatively is **easy to learn** than Scrapy.
2. The extensions, support, community is larger for Scrapy than for BeautifulSoup.
3. Scrapy should be considered as a **Spider** while BeautifulSoup is a **Parser**.