# Extracting paragraph text including other element's content using Scrapy Selector

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

Using [Scrapy 0.24 Selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), I want to extract the paragraph content including other element's content (in the following exemple, it'd be the anchor `<a>`. How can I achieve that?

## The Code

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> html = """
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <p>Hello, can I get this paragraph content without this <a href="http://google.com">Google link</a>?
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        """
>>> sel = Selector(text=html, type="html")
>>> sel.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
[u'Hello, can I get this paragraph content with this ', u'?']
```

## Output

```
[u'Hello, can I get this paragraph content with this ', u'?']
```

## Expected output

```
[u'Hello, can I get this paragraph content with this Google link?']
```

Comment: Hm. You could first extract the contents of what's in `<a href`s... and then parse that. An example of how to start on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997525/python-replace-with-regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend BeautifulSoup. While scrapy is a complete crawling framework, BS is a strong parsing library ([Difference between BeautifulSoup and Scrapy crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687421/difference-between-beautifulsoup-and-scrapy-crawler)).

Doc: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Install: `pip install beautifulsoup4`

For your case:

```
# 'html' is the one your provided
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
res = [p.get_text().strip() for p in soup.find_all('p')]
```

Result:

```
[u'Hello, can I get this paragraph content without this Google link?']
```