# scraping more tag value bs4 and other library

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the following HTML:

```
<select id="sizeShoe" name="attributes[&#39;size&#39;]" class="selectFld col-xs-12">
<option value="">Select Size</option>
<option value="025">2.5</option>
<option value="035">3.5</option>
<option value="040">4</option>
<option value="045">4.5</option>
<option value="050">5</option>
<option value="055">5.5</option>
<option value="060">6</option>
<option value="065">6.5</option>
<option value="070">7</option>
<option value="075">7.5</option>
<option value="080">8</option>
<option value="085" selected="selected">8.5</option>
<option value="090">9</option>
                        </select>
```

I need to create a dictionary with the following value:

```
argument = {"2.5":"025", "3.5":"035, "4":"040" ecc...}
```

My attempt:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

argument = {}
sizeShoe = soup.find("select", attrs={'id' : 'sizeShoe'})
for a in sizeShoe:
   valor = sizeShoe.get("value")
```

But the result of  `valor` is `None`.

How can I scrape the data and save it as dictionary?
And there is a library faster than BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a faster library than BeautifulSoup?

Check out [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).  See [Difference between BeautifulSoup and Scrapy crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19687421/12349734)

---

Try the following code to scrape the data to a dictionary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '''YOUR ABOVE CODE SNIPPET'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

shoe_size = soup.select_one('#sizeShoe')

# Check that 'tag' is not an instance of 'NavigableString'
# Check that the value of 'value' is not an empty string

argument = {
    tag.text: tag['value']
    for tag in shoe_size
    if not isinstance(tag, NavigableString) and tag['value']
}

print(argument)
```

Output:

```
{'2.5': '025', '3.5': '035', '4': '040', '4.5': '045', '5': '050', '5.5': '055', '6': '060', '6.5': '065', '7': '070', '7.5':'075', '8': '080', '8.5': '085', '9': '090'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the code here :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result_dict = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
for option in soup.find_all('option'):
    if option['value'] != '':
        result_dict[option.text] = option['value']
```

result_dict:

{'2.5': '025',
'3.5': '035',
'4': '040',
'4.5': '045',
'5': '050',
'5.5': '055',
'6': '060',
'6.5': '065',
'7': '070',
'7.5': '075',
'8': '080',
'8.5': '085',
'9': '090'}

Answer (score -1):

You have to use soup.find_all() instead of soup.find(). bs4 is the best there is.